# VHDL beta function

Tags: matlab, math, statistics, vhdl

A friend of mine needs to implement some statistical calculations in hardware.
She wants it to be accomplished using VHDL.

(cross my heart, I haven't written a line of code in VHDL and know nothing about its subtleties)

In particular, she needs a direct analogue of MATLAB's `betainc` function.

Is there a good package around for doing this?
Any hints on the implementation are also highly appreciated.
If it's not a good idea at all, please tell me about it as well.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the final result need to be synthesizable? (IE: the final product is on a chip)

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a core available that performs an incomplete beta function in the Xilinx toolset. I can't speak for the other toolsets available, although I would doubt that there is such a thing.

What Xilinx does offer is a set of signal processing blocks, like multipliers, adders and RAM Blocks (amongst other things, filters, FFTs), that can be used together to implement various custom signal transforms.

In order for this to be done, there needs to be a complete understanding of the inner workings of the transform to be applied.

A good first step is to implement the function "manually" in matlab as a proof of concept:

- Instead of using the built-in function in matlab, your friend can try to implement the function just using fundamental operators like multipliers and adders.
- The results can be compared with those produced by the built-in function for verification.
- The concept can then be moved to VHDL using the building blocks that are provided.

Doing this for the incomplete beta function isn't something for the faint-hearted, but it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no tool which allow interface of VHDL and matlab.

But interface of VHDL and C is fairly easy, so if you can implement your code(MATLAB's betainc function) in C then it can be done easily with FLI(foreign language interface).

If you are using modelsim below link can be helpful.

[link](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~ece327/old/2007t1/protected/modelsim/se_html/se_fli/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=FLIReference&file=fli_intro10.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But can it be implemented in VHDL only without any language interfaces?

Comment: FLI isn't synthesizeable, is it?

Comment: The people behind matlab actually make a tool to convert matlab to HDL: http://www.mathworks.com/products/hdl-coder/

Answer (score 2):

First of all a word of warning, if you haven't done any VHDL/FPGA work before, this is probably not the best place to start. With VHDL (and other HDL languages) you are basically describing hardware, rather than a sequential line of commands to execute on a processor (as you are with C/C++, etc.). You thus need a completely different skill- and mind-set when doing FPGA-development. Just because something can be written in VHDL, it doesn't mean that it actually can work in an FPGA chip (that it is synthesizable).

With that said, Xilinx (one of the major manufacturers of FPGA chips and development tools) does provide the [System Generator](http://www.xilinx.com/tools/sysgen.htm) package, which interfaces with Matlab and can automatically generate code for FPGA chips from this. I haven't used it myself, so I'm not at all sure if it's usable in your friend's case - but it's probably a good place to start.

The [System Generator User guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_1/sysgen_user.pdf) (link is on the previously linked page) also provides a short introduction to FPGA chips in general, and in the context of using it with Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

You COULD write it yourself. However, the incomplete beta function is an integral. For many values of the parameters (as long as both are greater than 1) it is fairly well behaved. However, when either parameter is less than 1, a singularity arises at an endpoint, making the problem a bit nasty. The point is, don't write it yourself unless you have a solid background in numerical analysis.

Anyway, there are surely many versions in C available. Netlib must have something, or look in Numerical Recipes. Or compile it from MATLAB. Then link it in as nav_jan suggests.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to VHDL, you could use [MyHDL](http://www.myhdl.org) to write and test your beta function - that can produce synthesisable (ie. can go into an FPGA chip) VHDL (or Verilog as you wish) out of the back end.

MyHDL is an extra set of modules on top of Python which allow hardware to be modelled, verified and generated.  Python will be a much more familiar environment to write validation code in than VHDL (which is missing many of the abstract data types you might take for granted in a programming language).

The code under test will still have to be written with a "hardware mindset", but that is usually a smaller piece of code than the test environment, so in some ways less hassle than figuring out how to work around the verification limitations of VHDL.